# Pycharm does not recognise @pytest.mark decorators

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, pytest, python-decorators

I want to tag/mark my tests with py.test decorators like in the [documentation](https://pytest.org/dev/mark.html) , but Pycharm does not recognise the mark module.
Also, mark does not exist in the auto completion options.

I have the latest py.test version installed [2.9.1].

All the posts and tutorials that I have read do not mention any problem accessing the module. Does my installation missing something ?

[image]

Comment: Is the pytest location marked as "sources" in your solution config?

Comment: pytest does some monkey patching that makes some of it modules not discoverable in normal ways. PyCharm has worked around some, but not all, of these. Markers is one that needs to be fixed. They know about it.

Comment: Thanks @PaulEveritt ! That is indeed frustrating... :[

Comment: Yeah.. have the same problem. Even 2.5 years later.. Do people who use Pycharm not use pytest that much? Its the foremost python testing framework these days?

Comment: Completely agree :(

Answer (score 0):

If you pip installed pytest, your pycharm will probably not recognise it. Install pytest from the pycharm packages and your issue should be solved.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have noticed this many times. Why is that?

Comment: I am not particularly sure but I think it has something to do with Pycharm's virtualenv setting. I have had situations where all I had to do was restart Pycharm or just change the interpreter. There is also an option on Pycharm that allows you to use globally installed variables. So it just depends on whatever works